# How to properly transform vertices for a model loaded using Assimp?

Tags: opengl, c++, assimp

When I try to load a **DAE** model then vertices are not placed correctly. Here's the code snippet I use to load 3D models using Assimp  :

```
aiNode* CGameObject::findNode(aiNode* rootNode, const char *name) {
    if (!strcmp(name, rootNode->mName.data)) {
        return rootNode;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rootNode->mNumChildren; i++) {
        aiNode *found = findNode(rootNode->mChildren[i], name);
        if (found) {
            return found;
        }

    }
    return NULL;

}

void CGameObject::transformNode(aiMatrix4x4 *result, aiNode* rootNode) {
    if (rootNode->mParent) {
        transformNode(result, rootNode->mParent);
        aiMultiplyMatrix4(result, &rootNode->mTransformation);
    } else {
        *result = rootNode->mTransformation;
    }
}                


Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFileFromMemory(buffer,
        size,
        aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace      |
        aiProcess_Triangulate           |
        aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
        aiProcess_GenUVCoords   |
        aiProcess_TransformUVCoords |
        aiProcess_FlipUVs |
        aiProcess_SortByPType);

    if (!scene) {
        return false;
    }

    const int iVertexTotalSize = sizeof(aiVector3D) * 2 + sizeof(aiVector2D);
    int iTotalVertices = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < scene->mNumMeshes; i++) {
        _Mesh* m = new _Mesh;

        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[i];

        aiNode* node = findNode(scene->mRootNode, mesh->mName.data);
        transformNode(&node->mTransformation, node);
        aiTransposeMatrix4(&node->mTransformation);

        int iMeshFaces = mesh->mNumFaces;
        for (int f = 0; f < iMeshFaces; f++) {

            const aiFace* face = &mesh->mFaces[f];

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                int vertexIndex = face->mIndices[k];
                iTotalVertices++;
                aiVector3D pos = mesh->mVertices[vertexIndex];

                aiTransformVecByMatrix4(&pos, &node->mTransformation);

                m->vertices.push_back(pos.x);
                m->vertices.push_back(pos.y);
                m->vertices.push_back(pos.z);
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong ? I will create a VBO for all the vertex positions later and render them.
When I load an **OBJ** model everything loads fine and there is no need for applying per-node transformations.

Also, I noticed that **Assimp** renames node names from "Cube.001" to "Cube_001", is this behavior normal/expected.
I'm using Assimp 3.1.1.